# ios/objective-c: How to move view when button pressed

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

To move the view when a textfield is selected (bringing the textfield to the vertical center of the view), I am using textFieldDidBeginEditing and then when the user finishes, textFieldDidEndEditing to move the view back where it started.

This accomplishes the goal.

However, when it comes time for the user to press a submit button, a defect of the above is that the view shifts back before the VC disappears creating a jarring transition.

I would like the button to stay in the same place or at least have some control over the view in relation to the button.

Is there a way to exempt pressing the button from textFieldDidEndEditing or alternatively, is there a method similar to textFieldDidBeginEditing that applies to buttons so you can keep them in the center of the view.

This is what I am using for the textField

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)sender
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:.3];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:TRUE];
    if ([sender isEqual:_username]) {
    self.view.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x, self.view.frame.origin.y -70., self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
           }
    else if([sender isEqual:_password]) {
         self.view.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x, self.view.frame.origin.y -90., self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
    }
    else if([sender isEqual:_Email]) {
        self.view.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x, self.view.frame.origin.y -110., self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
    }
```

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: why are you doing self.view.frame? It is the only view for view controller, you shouldnt be changing the self.view.frame. Try adding a view to self.view and change its frame.

Comment: [UIView commitAnimations]; ?

Comment: it is in a scrollview.

Comment: A combo of returning `NO` at `textFieldShouldEndEditing:` and triggering `[self.view endEditing: YES]` with some delay comes to mind. But this really depends on what you want to achieve...

Answer (score 0):

You could set a flag in your view controller when the submit button is pressed and if the flag is set not do the scrolling animation on `textFieldDidEndEditing`.

Comment: The textFieldDidEndEditing fires before the submit button fires when you touch it.  That is part of the problem.

Comment: In that case you could try to use the resignFirstResponder / becomeFirstResponder functions of the textField and button - maybe you can get which will be the next first responder (which will be the button) and react accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the desired life cycle of the textfield delegate for the textfield, you can try setting the textfield delegate for that textfield to nil as the first line of code in method called when the submit button is pressed. If you do this then the textFieldDidEndEditing delegate method will not be called for that textfield and you will not have the jarring transition.